# Comparing two IP Addresses in Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ip-address

I am trying to find if two ip addresses are the same or not. I admit that I am new with bash, but I see no reason this would not work:

```
if [[ "$IPAddress" != "$OLDIPAddress" ]]
then
  echo "IP Not the Same"
else
  echo "IP Same"
fi
```

For testing purposes, I have even hard coded the values for the two variables, and they still don't show up as the same. I know you don't always see your own typos, but I do not see why this would not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us how `$IPAddress` and `$OLDIPAddress` are defined.

Comment: What are the two values? Even the test ones. What do you get if you send them both to `xxd` or `hexdump`?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the same"... Is "127.0.0.1" "the same" as "127.000.000.001"? If so, then simple text comparison is going to be insuffucient...

Comment: @twalberg Octal definition is really rarely seen. It is unlikely that this is the reason, but hey! still good point! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Wasn't necessarily thinking octal, although that's a valid observation as well... I was thinking more of a form-based entry that might return the equivalent of e.g. `printf "%03d" x` for each octet... Never trust input....

Comment: @twalberg A leading zero in a section of an IP indicates that the value of the section should be interpreted as an octal number. I've learned that a couple of months ago :)

Comment: @hek2mgl In C and in C++ and some other contexts, yes, but that's not universally true...

Comment: @twalberg That is indeed unversially true. It is defined in the RFC.. Let me find it again.... Hex numbers can be used as well, also number systems can be mixed. Try `ping 127.0x0.00.1`

Comment: @hek2mgl Try putting "0177.0.0.1 localhost" in `/etc/hosts`... Doesn't  work on my current system (Ubuntu 12.04.3). Definitely not universal...

Comment: `while read site; do
  #echo $site

  #IPAddress=`ping -c 1 $site | head -1 | cut -d '(' -f2 | cut -d ')' -f1`
  IPAddress="192.168.1.1"
  echo $IPAddress
  #OldIPAddress=`cat $site.log | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1`
  OldIPAddress="192.168.1.1"
  echo $OldIPAddress

  if [[ "$IPAddress" != "$OLDIPAddress" ]]
    then
      echo "IP Not the Same"
      echo $IPAddress `date` >> $site.log
    else
      echo "IP Same"
  fi

done <ping.list`

Comment: @twalberg This is because [RFC1123](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) (Section 2.1) restricts addresses to be in decimal notation in `/etc/hosts`. Just because one software does not implement a standard correctly, or just a subset of it, it does not mean that the standard isn't universal.

Comment: @hek2mgl I didn't follow closely the discussion, but in dot-decimal notation each number _SHOULD_ be expressed in decimal. As an example [some IANA tables](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc790) actually shows octet values in zero-filled three-digit *decimal*. However, _some implementations_ (notably BSD) allowed octal and hex using the C conversion. AFAIK, this is not enforced by any RFC. Anyway, as those implementations are widespread, it is _recommended_ to remove leading 0 in order to avoid ambiguities. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-00 for some details

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I really appreciated your feedback. I also couldn't find any RFC again, which describes the octal/hexadecimal notation. But I know *there is something*. That something was described (and linked) in a comment below the article I linked in my recent [blog article](http://www.metashock.de/2014/06/pcre-regex-to-match-ip-version-4-address-decimal-ascii-representation/) ... Unfortunately O'reilly has changed their forum archive since then (~3months ago). The comment isn't there anymore. So it keeps a miracle unless I can find it again. (will try archive.org) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your command should work, you can use the simple test operator (just a single bracket). The advantage is that it will work with any (POSIX) shell. However, the `[[` operator should work too.

Can you reproduce this little example? (Should output 'yes'):

```
IPAddress="127.0.0.1"
OLDIPAddress="127.0.0.1"

if [ "$IPAddress" != "$OLDIPAddress" ] ; then 
    echo "no"
else
    echo "yes"
fi
```

Comment: This is roughly how I was going about my test. The result I am getting is that the two IP addresses are NOT the same, even though, they clearly are. For reasons beyond my comprehention, this example returns not the same...

Comment: Have you copy/pasted *my* code and tried it? Without *any* changes?

Comment: yes. Copy and paste, the only thing I did was add a #!/bin/bash to the top.

Answer (score 4):

Quick demo script for comparing differently formated ip addresses, "normal" vs. DHCP always 3 digit octets for instance. Hopefully a couple of useful tricks you can use for parsing and validation in addition to compares, and a catalyst for some more from the community.  (This is my first post with code so hopefully it comes through ok - as always YMMV.)

```
#!/bin/bash
# demo.sh - parse, validate, compare ip addresses
# usage: demo.sh {ipaddress1} {ipaddress2}

#--- IP ADDRESS 1
#---   Is there anything besides digits and three dots?
#---   Parse out the octets
#---   There should be exactly 4 populated octets
#---   All 4 octets must not be > 255
[ "${1//[0-9]/}" != '...' ] && echo "invalid" && exit 1
O1=(${1//./ })
[ -z "${O1[3]}" -o -n "${O1[4]}" ] && echo "invalid" && exit 1
[ ${O1[0]} -gt 255 -o ${O1[1]} -gt 255 -o ${O1[2]} -gt 255 -o ${O1[3]} -gt 255 ] && echo "invalid" && exit 1
#--- IP ADDRESS 2
[ "${2//[0-9]/}" != '...' ] && echo "invalid" && exit 1
O2=(${2//./ })
[ -z "${O2[3]}" -o -n "${O2[4]}" ] && echo "invalid" && exit 1
[ ${O2[0]} -gt 255 -o ${O2[1]} -gt 255 -o ${O2[2]} -gt 255 -o ${O2[3]} -gt 255 ] && echo "invalid" && exit 1

#--- Numeric compares of each octet
echo "Comparing each octect"
if [ ${O1[0]} -eq ${O2[0]} ]
  then
    echo "  ${O1[0]} == ${O2[0]}"
  else
    echo "  ${O1[0]} != ${O2[0]}"
  fi
if [ ${O1[1]} -eq ${O2[1]} ]
  then
    echo "  ${O1[1]} == ${O2[1]}"
  else
    echo "  ${O1[1]} != ${O2[1]}"
  fi
if [ ${O1[2]} -eq ${O2[2]} ]
  then
    echo "  ${O1[2]} == ${O2[2]}"
  else
    echo "  ${O1[2]} != ${O2[2]}"
  fi
if [ ${O1[3]} -eq ${O2[3]} ]
  then
    echo "  ${O1[3]} == ${O2[3]}"
  else
    echo "  ${O1[3]} != ${O2[3]}"
  fi

#--- Numeric IP address compare
echo "Compare via long if"
if [ ${O1[0]} -eq ${O2[0]} -a ${O1[1]} -eq ${O2[1]} -a ${O1[2]} -eq ${O2[2]} -a ${O1[3]} -eq ${O2[3]} ]
  then
    echo "  ${1} == ${2}"
  else
    echo "  ${1} != ${2}"
  fi

#--- Loop for numeric compare
echo "Compare via loop"
SAME="Y"
for I in 0 1 2 3
  do
   echo "  loop ${I} compare ${O1[$I]} ${O2[$I]}"
   [ ${O1[$I]} -ne ${O2[$I]} ] && SAME="" && break
  done
echo "  result"
if [ -n "${SAME}" ]
  then
    echo "  ${1} == ${2}"
  else
    echo "  ${1} != ${2}"
  fi

exit


$ ./demo.sh 1.2.3.4 1.2.3
invalid
$ ./demo.sh 1.2.3.4 1.2.q.4
invalid
$ ./demo.sh 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4.
invalid
$ ./demo.sh 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4.5
invalid
$ ./demo.sh 1.2.3.4 1.2.300.4
invalid
$ ./demo.sh 1.02.3.004 01.2.003.4
Comparing each octect
  1 == 01
  02 == 2
  3 == 003
  004 == 4
Compare via long if
  1.02.3.004 == 01.2.003.4
Compare via loop
  loop 0 compare 1 01
  loop 1 compare 02 2
  loop 2 compare 3 003
  loop 3 compare 004 4
  result
  1.02.3.004 == 01.2.003.4
$ ./demo.sh 1.02.3.004 01.2.030.4
Comparing each octect
  1 == 01
  02 == 2
  3 != 030
  004 == 4
Compare via long if
  1.02.3.004 != 01.2.030.4
Compare via loop
  loop 0 compare 1 01
  loop 1 compare 02 2
  loop 2 compare 3 030
  result
  1.02.3.004 != 01.2.030.4
$
```